# Support for the experimental syntax jsx isn't enabled when setting up Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

Trying to setup jest to work on my react app, but getting the error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
...
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (5:10):
```

I read quite a few answers on SO for this, but nothing I have tried has worked so far. Here is the code I have in `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets:[
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

This is what I have in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
      },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
}
```

This is what I have in `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-textfit": "^1.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0"
  }
}
```